# Permutations reusing PHP code in JQuery with passing by reference issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Original code:

```
// function to generate and print all N! permutations of $str. (N = strlen($str)).
function permute($str,$i,$n) {
   if ($i == $n)
       print "$str\n";
   else {
        for ($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++) {
          swap($str,$i,$j);
          permute($str, $i+1, $n);
          swap($str,$i,$j); // backtrack.
       }
   }
}

// function to swap the char at pos $i and $j of $str.
function swap(&$str,$i,$j) {
    $temp = $str[$i];
    $str[$i] = $str[$j];
    $str[$j] = $temp;
}   

$str = "hey";
permute($str,0,strlen($str)); // call the function.
```

I would like to reuse this code with permutations for my jquery so here is my code:

```
div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="word">
</div>
<div id="combinations">
    <p>

    </p>
</div>

<script>
    function permute(str,i,n) {
           if (i == n)
                $('p').append(str+" ");
           else {
                for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                  swap(str,i,j);
                  permute(str, i+1, n);
                  swap(str,i,j); // backtrack.
               }
           }
        }

        // function to swap the char at pos $i and $j of $str.
    function swap(str,i,j) {
        var temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = temp;
    }   

    $('#word').on('input',function(e){
        var str = $("#word").val();
        if(str == ''){
            $('p').empty();
        }
        if(str.length != strOld){
            $('p').empty();
        }
        var strOld = str.length;

        permute(str, 0,str.length)


    });
</script>
```

So in that paragraph I would like to display all the permutations from users input so if user inputs AB it will display AB BA and so on I'm not really sure how can I change &$str from the original one to JQuery I've read a few other stack questions about passing by reference in JS/JQuery and I couldn't really grasp my head around it.

Right now this code doesn't produce any errors it just displays whatever user inputs the exact copy of input field.

**UPDATE:** What I've tried with your suggestions:

```
function permute(str,i,n) {
           if (i == n)
                $('p').append(str+" ");
           else {
                for (j = i; j < n; j++) {
                  str = swap(str,i,j);
                  permute(str, i+1, n);
                  str = swap(str,i,j); // backtrack.
               }
           }
        }

    function swap(str,i,j) {
        str = str.split("");
        var temp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = temp;
        return str.join("");
    }   


        var str = "hey";
        permute(str, 0,str.length)
```

It displayed only hey nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the JS version of your PHP code:

```
function permute( str, i, n ) {
   if ( i == n ){
      console.log(str);     
   } else {
        for ( var j = i; j < n; j++) {
          str = swap( str, i, j );
          permute( str, i+1, n );
          str = swap( str, i, j ); // backtrack.
       }
   }
}

// function to swap the char at pos $i and $j of $str.
function swap( str, i, j ) {
    str = str.split("");
    var temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = temp;
    return str.join("");
}   

var str = "hey";
permute( str, 0, str.length ); // call the function.
```

And here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/learnjavascript/9q88axnt/)

Comment: I don't really understand why doesn't it loop for 2 letters 2! times for 3 3! etc it if I type A it will display A if i type AB it will display AB instead of AB BA it only display the input (i'm using your code)

Comment: Have you checked the [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/learnjavascript/9q88axnt/)?

Comment: Oh yeah that works fine is there a way to make it work on change without the button? (I've updated the question what I've tried)

Comment: Yep. You can add a `keyup` event on the input field.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't know by ref parameters for functions. Some people say it does, because objects are passed by reference, but that's actually not the case. Objects are reference types, meaning that an object variable is a reference itself (to the object data), but you still pass the variable itself by value, so you cannot change it.

But in this case it's not even about object but about strings.

I think the simplest solution is to return the new string:

```
  function swap(str,i,j) {
    var temp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = temp;
    return str;
  }
```

And then call it like this:

```
  str = swap(str,i,j);
```

Comment: Affecting value to `str[x]` don't work!: It must be temporarily casted to array like @KostasX showed.